# Is it safe to upgrade from Ubuntu 16.10 to 17.04?

Tags: upgrade, updates, update-manager, do-release-upgrade, 17.04

I became a linux user with 16.10, about 4 months ago. I'm loving it, but since the final version of 17.04 is about to come out, I'd like to upgrade. Is there any benefit to a clean install? I don't really want to have to reinstall, but if there's anything, *anything*, that would give me a reason to clean install, I'll do it. I prefer to go on the safe road. Also, how do I update? With `update-manager -d` and following the instructions, with `sudo apt dist-upgrade`, or with `sudo do-release-upgrade`?

Comment: 17.04 is off-topic at this site till the release.

Comment: @Pilot6 passing your mouse on the tag clearly says it's off topic to say general questions about it. For example, you should not use it with questions about something which is the same for all versions. Now tell me how a question about upgrading to 17.04 is a general question regarding all versions.

Comment: I don't see how any part of this question is specific to 17.04, but then I'm not much of a cutting-edge guy.

Answer (score 4):

just did the upgrade from 16.04 to 16.10 to 17.04. Had an issue with the network manager not starting on 16.10. The upgrade from 16.10 to 17.04 was smooth but I'm having some issues with my VPN service at the moment. My network connection has been stable though. I used the software & update UI but you can follow the official upgrade doc: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ZestyZapus/ReleaseNotes